# configuring search server express 2010 to search inside pdf documents

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-express

configuring search server express 2010 to search inside pdf documents ,

I have installed the adobe pdf ifilter by following the below steps

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/PDFiFIlterSharePoint2010.aspx

after i installed the pdf ifilter i started a full crawl , when i try to search words inside of the documents it does not incude words inside of pdf documents

my environment

sharepoint foundation 2010

search server express 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sharepointde1tuke,
                 Make sure you re crawl your search database again.Do a full crawl.
Hope that helps.Can't remember the syntax.If you still have issues let me know

Comment: It is a combination of doing the crawl and repasting the pdf key in the registry that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to install Windows Desktop Search to check if PDFs are searchable from there. If they aren't you have a iFilter-Problem otherwise its a SharePoint/SearchServer-Problem.

Another thing you could do is restarting the search services (like "osearch") or -if possible- restart the whole server.

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: I will try and report back